# How to use HeaderFooter class in itextSharp 5.2.1 dll

Tags: itext

I have used itextSharp 4.1.2 dll .There HeaderFooter class is there .But in itextSharp 5.2.1 dll I am not getting HeaderFooter class.So can any one tell me how to use same functionality  using itextSharp 5.2.1 dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HeaderFooter` class was removed in iText(Sharp) 5, see the last item of the [5.0.0 changelog](http://itextpdf.com/history/?branch=50&node=500).

Adding headers and footers is achieved with a much more practical paradigm: page events. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032614/itextsharp-creating-a-footer-page-of) and the corresponding answers for an example on how to use page events.

Comment: You're welcome! If my answer is resolving your issue, please consider accepting it.