# iTextSharp positioning 'page of pages' text in the footer

Tags: asp.net, itext

[This example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032614/itextsharp-creating-a-footer-page-of) shows how to write 'page of pages' in the footer of a pdf document. Basically it uses a template for the total number of pages, and this template is updated in the onCloseDocument event. From what I see, the example assumes that the total number of pages is less than 10 (only one digit); if the total number of pages exceeds 9, the position of the preceding text (Page x of) is incorrect, when the text is horizontally aligned right. Is there an easy way to solve this issue?

Comment: If you need a really good looking layout, you need the exact number of pages before starting to draw the numbers. Thus, instead of the page event solution, you should use the 2 pass solution.

Comment: I didn't know about the 2 pass solution. This comment actually answered my question.